# Python NLP Topic Modeling - Using TfidfVectorizer and LSI model for topics outputs characters instead of words

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, nlp

I am trying to perform topic modeling NLP on a dataframe of blog articles using TfidfVectorizer and an LSI model for topic modeling. However, I get an output of characters instead of words as expected.

```
#LSI model

X = df["articles"] 

# Model pipeline setup. 
# You can select the model by uncommenting and commenting it. 
model = Pipeline(
    [
        ("vectorizer", TfidfVectorizer(analyzer=raw_token_input, stop_words='en', min_df=1)),  
        ("lsi", TruncatedSVD(n_components=10, algorithm='randomized', n_iter=100)), 
    ]
)

# Execute the topic clustering. 
X_latent_feature = model.fit_transform(X) 
component = mlpipe_topic["lsi"].components_

# Get feature names
feature_names = model["vectorizer"].get_feature_names() 
print(feature_names)
```

Desired output:
I should be getting words related to the topics, but I get only characters like 'a', 'z', '!' instead.

Comment: Here the problem seems related to `analyzer=raw_token_input`. Please provide the related code.

Comment: usually when you get single chars instead words then it can means it expected list of strings but it got single string which Python threads as list of chars.

Comment: Thank you for the help! It was indeed the raw_token_input, and worked when I took it out. Not sure why the function is:

`def raw_token_input(tokens:list) -> list:
    return tokens`